# css radiobox hide inner circle to change style

Tags: html, css

How can i hide the inner circle of a radiobox to change the style to cornered. Please see the picture below.

[image: radioImage]

**CSS:**

```
input[type="radio"]
{
  width: 166px;
  height: 32px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked
{
  background-position: -36px -232px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide *just* the button, so you have to hide the entire element.  You can wrap the `<input>` and another element such as a `<span>` in a label, hide the input, and apply all of the styles to the `<span>` instead (or use the `<label>` with the appropriate `for`/`id` combination).

http://jsfiddle.net/fapYX/

Comment: your solution is great. Like to have a frame around the box. I've wrap a div around, but its hides the radiobox completely.